# EJB Spec Violation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jboss-tools

I created an EJB 2 named EvenementBean for test. I then deleted it. and whenever trying to deploy my .ear project now, I get these errors :

```
    WARN [verifier] EJB sepc violation:
    Bean: Evenement
    Section: 22.2
    Warning: The Bean Provider must specify the fully-qualified name of the Java class 
    that implements the enterprise bean's business methods in the <ejb-class> element.

    Info : class not found on 'com.afb.iard.sina.evenement.EvenementBean' : No 
    ClassLoaders found for : com.afb.iard.sina.evenement.EvenementBean.

    Could not create deployment: File:/E:/DIR1/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/ABrain/tmp/deploy
    /tmp...
    org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Verification of Enterprise Beans failed, 
    see above.
```

I am using jboss-ide 1.6. and I've already restarted the IDE several times without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to delete also the reference entry in the ejb descriptor ( I think it is ejb-jar.xml )

Comment: thanks, I deleted the ejb-jar.xml file and deployed again. now, it works fine. but I still can't access the deployed ejbs from a client. I get a javax.naming.CommunicationException: could not obtain connection to the url .

do you know how I can solve this ?

Comment: Ouch, I think you should not delete the whole file, but only the entry where your deleted bean was mentioned. MMhh otherwise, nope, sorry. Perhaps you'll have to open a new question.

Comment: actually, I deleted the whole file and JBoss-IDE generated a new one for me when I hit the "run packinging" button, so no problem there.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect something in one of your deployment descriptors is out-of-date, and therefore JBoss is trying to load the `.class` file for the bean you have since deleted.